# Redux Observable cancel previous requests

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, axios, redux-observable

I have an epic which emits multiple actions

```
export const abc = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(fetchAllSearchOptions)),
    mergeMap((action) => {
      return concat(
        concat(
          of(fetchOptions({term: 'a', ...action.payload})),
          of(fetchOptions({term: 'b', ...action.payload})),
          of(fetchOptions({term: 'c', ...action.payload})),
          ),
          concat(
            of(fetchOptions({term: 'd', ...action.payload})),
            of(fetchOptions({term: 'e', ...action.payload})),
            of(fetchOptions({term: 'f', ...action.payload})),
        )
      )
    })
  );
```

`fetchOptions` has mergeMap so all calls can be sent but it doesn't cancel the pending requests on param change.

This calls 6 requests to server & if any param changes we call this again. This calls a lot of requests to server but doesn't cancel the previous ones. How
How do I cancel previous requests

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`. `mergeMap` doesn't cancel any subscriptions arising from previous values, but `switchMap` always does.